# display subviews with delay

Tags: iphone

When this action gets executed it displays secondviewcontroller directly what i want is that viewcontroller displays first and after 40 or 50 secs it displays secondviewcontroller next and so on.

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{
PageOneViewController *viewController = [[PageOneViewController alloc] init];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; 

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

[self.view sendSubviewToBack:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

}
```

Anyone have any ideas how i can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the secondViewController in a separate method and call that method using  [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender {

PageOneViewController *viewController = [[PageOneViewController alloc] init];    
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); 
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[self performSelector:@selector(secondViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:40];  
}


-(void)secondViewController {

SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:secondController.view];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try making the view invisible and then quickly fading it in after 40 seconds have passed.

```
secondController.view.alpha = 0.0;
[self.view addSubview:secondController.view];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
            delay:40 
            options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
            animations:^{
                secondController.view.alpha = 1.0;
            }
            completion:NULL
];
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative/addition to the method detailed by Aravindhanarviless is to use an NSTimer:

```
self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:40 target:self selector:@selector(showSecondViewController) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```